# Getting cards in hand Java

Tags: java

I am currently writing a modified version of Gin Rummy. My problem is I am new to arrays and I am trying to get each player to hold 5 random cards generated in my Card class. How do I make it so I can put 5 random cards into each players hand? Here is my Card class...

```
{  
String suit;  
String rank; 
int score;
int a;  
int b;
final int CARDS_IN_SUIT = 13;
final int SUITS_IN_DECK = 4;
public GinCard(String suit, String rank, int score, int a, int b){
    this.suit = "";
    this.rank = "";
    this.score = 0;
    this.a = 0;
    this.b = 0; 
}
   //Sets up the cards(Suits and ranks)
public GinCard(){           
    switch(a){
    case 1:
        suit = "Clubs";
        break;
    case 2:
        suit = "Diamonds";
        break;
    case 3:
        suit = "Hearts";
        break;
    default:
        suit = "Spades";
        break;
    }
    switch(b){
    case 1:
        rank = "Ace";
        break;
    case 2:
        rank ="2";
        break;
    case 3:
        rank ="3";
        break;
    case 4:
        rank ="4";
        break;
    case 5:
        rank ="5";
        break;
    case 6:
        rank ="6";
        break;  
    case 7:
        rank ="7";
        break;  
    case 8:
        rank ="8";
        break;
    case 9:
        rank ="9";
        break;
    case 10:
        rank ="10";
        break;
    case 11:
        rank = "Jack";
        break;
    case 12:
        rank = "Queen";
        break;
    case 13:
        rank = "King";
        break;
    default:
        break;
        }  

    switch(score){
    case 1:
        score = 15;
        break;
    case 2:
        score = 5;
        break;
    case 3:
        score = 5;
        break;
    case 4:
        score = 5;
        break;
    case 5:
        score = 5;
        break;
    case 6:
        score = 5;
        break;
    case 7:
        score = 5;
        break;
    case 8:
        score = 5;
        break;
    case 9:
        score = 5;
        break;
    case 10:
        score = 5;
        break;
    case 11:
        score = 10;
        break;
    case 12:
        score = 10;
        break;
    case 13:
        score = 10;
        break;

    }
}
//Returns the value of the rank
int getRank(){    
    return b;  
}
//Returns the value of the suit in case of a draw in ranks
int getSuit(){
    return a;   
}  
int getScore(){
    return score;
}
public void deal() 
{
    a = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % SUITS_IN_DECK + 1);  
    b = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % CARDS_IN_SUIT + 1);  
}
 }
```

and here is my main program so far...

```
public class GinRummy {

public static final int CARDS_IN_HAND = 5;

public void RummyHand(){
    int[] hand = new int[CARDS_IN_HAND];

};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    GinCard player = new GinCard();
    GinCard player2 = new GinCard();
```

Comment: What's the error you get? If you don't get an error, what does it output versus what do you expect?

Comment: So far no error. What I am trying to do is put cards into the hand aka the array. I am just learning arrays so I am need some guidance on how to do that

Comment: Anyway, you have defined two constructors for `GinCard` but neither do what you think they should. The first one will ignore its arguments and set everything to `0` or `""`, and the second one tries to reference its member variables before they've been instantiated. Rethink your constructors first. I suggest implementing `toString()` so you can print your cards to see what they look like after you make them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set set = new HashSet();
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

while (set.size() < 5) {
    set.add(randomGenerator.nextInt(52));
}
```

Now set contains 5 unique cards for the a player.

Then translate 0-51 into the 52 cards in a deck and you have a 5 card had for each player.

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution consists of two classes. One is a card class, other is card manager class (dealer). Card class contains fields that describe it's rank, suit and score. Score is calculated from rank. By the way, I only left String-typed suit and rank here because you had it like that, you should really use ENUMs to store such things.

Card manager contains business logic. Method used for dealing cards (or generating them) creates instances of GinCard class. Each instance is added to list of five chosen cards only if it has not been added to any other list (aka, has not been dealt to anyone yet), otherwise it randoms it again. Method gets called for each player's hand.

In the end manager class evaluates the score of players' hands based on the sum of scores of each card in their hand.

Card class:

```
public class GinCard() {

private String suit; 
private String rank;
private int score = 0;

// getters and setters for those 3


public GinCard(final int suit, final int rank) {
    this.suit = getSuitString(suit);
    this.rank = getRankString(rank);
    this.score = getScoreByRank(rank);
}

private int getScoreByRank(final int rank) {
    switch(score){
    case 1:
        return 15;
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
        return 5;    
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
        return 10;
    default: 
        return 0;
    }
}
private String getRankString(final int rank) {
     switch(b){
    case 1:
        return "Ace";
    case 2:
        return "2";        
    case 3:
        return "3";
    case 4:
        return "4";    
    case 5:
        return "5";        
    case 6:
        return "6";        
    case 7:
        return "7";    
    case 8:
        return ="8";  
    case 9:
        return "9";       
    case 10:
        return "10";    
    case 11:  
        return "Jack";    
    case 12:
        return "Queen";
    case 13:
        return "King";
}

private String getSuitString(final int suit) {
  switch(a){
    case 1:
        return "Clubs";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "Diamonds";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "Hearts";
        break;
    default:
        return "Spades";
        break;
   }
}
```

}

Make some generator class:

```
public class CardManager {

/** Generate one five-card hand */
public List<GinCard> generateHand(final List<GinCard> globallyChosenCards) {
    final Random random = new Random();
    final List<GinCard> currentChosenCards = new ArrayList<GinCard>();
    while(currentChosenCards.size < 5) {
        final int suit = rand.nextInt() * 4 + 1; 
        final int rank = rand.nextInt() * 13 + 1;

        if (!isCardChosen(globallyChosenCards, suit, rank) && !isCardChosen(chosenCards, suit, rank) {
            final GinCard chosenCard = new GinCard(suit, rank);
            currentChosenCards.add(chosenCard);
            globallyChosenCards.add(chosenCard);
        }                                    
    }
    return currentChosenCards;
}

public int evaluateScore(final List<GinCard> hand) {
    final int totalScore = 0;
    for (final GinCard card : hand) {
        totalScore += card.getScore();
    }
    return totalScore;
}

/** Check if card is already chosen by someone */
private boolean isCardChosen(final List<GinCard> chosenCards, final int chosenSuit, final int chosenRank) {
      for (final GinCard chosenCard : chosenCards) {
           if (chosenCard.getSuit().equals(chosenSuit) && chosenCard.getRank().equals(chosenRank)) {
               return true;
           }
      }
      return false;
}
```

}

Create objects and call methods where you want:

```
final CardManager cardManager = new CardManager();
final List<GinCard> allPlayersCards = new ArrayList<GinCard>();
final List<GinCard> playerOneHand = cardManager.generateHand(allPlayersCards);
final List<GinCard> playerTwoHand = cardManager.generateHand(allPlayersCards);
final int playerOneScore = cardManager.evaluateScore(playerOneHand);
final int playerTwoScore = cardManager.evaluateScore(playerTwoHand);
if (playerOneScore > playerTwoScore) {
    // player one wins
} else if (playerOneScore < playerTwoScore) {
    // player two wins
} else {
    // tie
}
```

In theory it should work, haven't tried it though so there might be some errors and typos here and there. Of course it's very simplified, you should use Enums for RANK and SUIT, for example.

Comment: The points are the score for each card. So basically ace is 15 points, 2-10 is 5, and the Jack, Queen, King are 10. My overall goal is to draw 5 cards for each player and then whoever has the most points, wins.

Comment: I edited the answer to take score into consideration.